# Make child grow with parent container

Tags: css, html, height

So, I have 2 Containers:

+-----------+
|               |
+---+        |
|     |         |
|     |         |
|     |         |
|     |         |
+---+------+

The parent hast an variable amount of content, so the child should grow to always go down to the bottom.

```
#logbody {
font-family: calibri;
width: 100%;
height: 85%;
background-color: #DFDFDF;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 16;
overflow: auto;
}

#menu {
float: left;
font-family: calibri;
width: 15%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #F8AA3C;
}
```

logbody is the parent, menu the child.
When the parent contains a lot of stuff it'll look like this:

+-----------+
|               |
+---+        |
|     |         |
|     |         |
|     |         |
|     |         |
+---+        |
|               |
+-----------+

And that's not what I want, the child should grow along. As you can see the parent is not at a 100% height since there's another container above the parent. Actually, there's one big continer, which is 100%. The first child is some kind of header with 12%, followed by the header, then the logbody which contains another child (the menu).

```
<div id=container> //100%
    <div id=header></div> //12%
    <div id=logbody> //85%
        <div id=menu></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know, this ain't proper code, it'S just to show the structure. And yes, the remaining 3% are on purpose.

So, is there any pure-CSS solution to adapt the height of the child (menu)?

Comment: so what you want to do is to stick the menu to the left,bottom corner of the longbody?

Comment: Uhm, I put your code in fiddle, and the #menu is being pushed by the parent. http://jsfiddle.net/GcSvN/1/

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos: If you use the whole code:
http://jsfiddle.net/GcSvN/3/
And this is kinda what happens to me, but my "stuff" isn't shiftet totally to the left, only about the amount that is 'missing' from the menu...

Comment: @V0R73X: Kinda, but it should grow in height, so the menu doesn't wander down when the parent grows...

Comment: Why are you trying to limit the divs vertically with the "height" declarations? I've never seen something like this and I bet you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a couple of lines to your CSS and it seems to work if I've understood the question correctly.

```
#logbody {
font-family: calibri;
width: 100%;
height: 85%;
background-color: #DFDFDF;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 16;
overflow: hidden; /*This is new*/
position: relative; /*As is this*/
}

#menu {
float: left;
font-family: calibri;
width: 15%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #F8AA3C;
position: absolute; /*This is new*/
}​
```

Note, this approach won't expand the parent if the child's height exceeds that of its parent what with the `overflow` being `hidden` and all.

Comment: well, the child's height shouldn't exceed, but in your solution i need the overflow. As long, as there's no overflow in the parent the child's height fits perfectly, but as soon as the parents 'grows' (is being overflowed and therefore scrolls) I need the child to follow that and expand...

Comment: Unless you're giving the parent a fixed height it shouldn't ever scroll, but just expand? http://jsfiddle.net/WzpZa/2/

Comment: But... you _are_ giving it a fixed height: 85%.
if I leave out the "overflow" part, it justs cuts it!

Comment: Oh wow, you solved one of the problems, and I didn't even realize it until now. My content of the parent below the menu has always been shifted to the left, and with your positioning this stopped.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to stretch the height of your sidebar, you can make the background behind your sidebar stretch the full length of the page, thus giving the appearance of equal heights. This effectively has the same effect (but note that this only works with fixed-width columns). This trick is known as the [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) technique and a pretty standard way of achieving equal-height columns.

Comment: Let me know if you have trouble implementing this solution or have any questions.

Comment: So, my basic problem is solved now, but I'll try this for beauty-reasonas as soon as I get home!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to maintain a visual column, you could move the styling to a wrapper element that goes around both elements. Actually making the column widths the same can't be done very easily with CSS.

Additionally, you can use pseudo-elements on #logbody to create the column background as well. A height on the pseudo-element will behave more like you might expect the child height to behave.

Comment: Can you explain that in more detail please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking, the answer is pretty clear and straightforward: There is **no** PURE CSS solution so that a CHILD element can grow depending on its PARENTS contents.
In CSS, an element will grow depending on either its OWN contents or on the contents of its CHILDREN . -

The only solutions you could have are two:

1) a Javascript solution. 
2) a fake column (faux columns) http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/